# Flat-file(s) based data storage vs SQL database

Tags: c#, xml, database, nhibernate

We were having a discussion today, with the subject being our data storage solution we use, being NHibernate. In the team, we have a strong opponent of this storage solution, as we have (often, in his words) lose time debugging things related to proxies and backward compatibility.

The application in which we use NHibernate is a 1D hydraulic simulation suite for simulating water flow in rivers, water quality, dealing with rainfall and working with both static and dynamically triggered hydraulic structures. The user defines a graphs that represents the river network, places structures on these graphs (and parameterize them), defines initial conditions (initial water levels, pollutant level etc) and driving data (rainfall, evaporation, chemical processes, etc). We deal with tabulated input data, both big and small, and GIS data, and off course the various 'real world abstraction' objects like bridges, lakes, local water discharge locations and many more.
We're continuously improving and extending the product and we've got already 3 releases out that we have to support, so backwards compatibility is an important factor.

Now I'll have to admit, I'm not a database-guy. I have very limited knowledge on the various storage solutions that exist and their pro's and con's. If it would be up to the afore mentioned colleague, our data store should be refactored to a flat-file(s) based solution storage, using XML files for example. (While I don't think this product is going to get such a refactoring, it might be that our next product might go for a full flat-file based storage solution)

I was just wondering, given the above general description, what would be the pro's and con's for either taking the flat-file based storage route compared to using NHibernate (or any comparative solution). Does my colleague have a good point and flat-files actually a superior data storage solution for this case? Or is he just very biased and might the main problem just be an insufficient understanding of how NHibernate works?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make much sense since you're comparing apples and orangutans. ASCII is a form of text encoding. It's got no relationship I'm aware of to any particular form of storage.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have to admit, when I first read your comment I thought you said `orangunuts`; I'm not sure how I got that but man it was funny then!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm sorry for the confusion. With ASCII storage (that's how my colleage names it), I mean that the data is persisted in plain text files. So instead of using NHibernate with a MySQL backend for example, he'd like to see a bunch of files that is humanly readable. For example, one parameterized bridge would be a file or maybe all parameterized bridges are aggregated into a single file. Does that better clarify the question?

Comment: Yes, so a more common way to express it would be Flat file(s) vs SQL database.

Comment: I've updated the title and question to the proper terminology :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it like this. If you have multiple users sharing the same data, and you need a repository to serve it, a database is what you want. If you're building "projects", much like Visual Studio, an XML based storage solution is probably more appropriate. For both portability and dependency control. Oh, and not to mention deployment.

It appears to me, based off your explanation, XML is a more appropriate storage format.

Comment: The application actually behaves in a similar way as Visual Studio does to be honest. There's a project, which has various models, which in turn have input and output data which can be related between each other. It has docking implemented, just like Visual Studio. Instead of compilation we have model validation and when okey you can run the endproduct.

Comment: @Xilconic, yeah I think the XML approach is the most appropriate here. It's local to the user, and portable in XML so it can be easily shared with others that are not connected to the network.